# getting last item in the array behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i have this function which is supposed to sort the array and then get the difference of the last item - the first item and add all the missing numbers in between, and then compare it to the original array and figure out how many numbers were added, so it works fine but on some test cases it behaves strangely where the last item indexed in the array is not the correct one below is the code and test cases

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    var sorted = statues.sort();
    var arr =[];
    var firstItem = sorted[0];
    var lastItem = sorted[sorted.length -1];
    var difference= lastItem-firstItem;
    var counter=0;

    for (var i=0;i<=difference;i++){
        arr.push(firstItem++);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(sorted.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    console.log(counter);
}

makeArrayConsecutive2([1,3,5]); //this works correctly and the output 
//is 2 since the numbers missing are 2 and 4 so 2 numbers

makeArrayConsecutive2([1,3,5,9,12]); //this outputs 5 when it should 
//output 7
```

can someone please help me because im going crazy cant figure out why its behaving like this!

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, the built-in `Array.sort()` sorts based on strings, not numbers. So even though you have an array of numbers, you need to pass a comparison function to the sort() method to ensure the values are sorted as numbers:

```js
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    var sorted = statues.sort(function (a,b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    var arr =[];
    var firstItem = sorted[0];
    var lastItem = sorted[sorted.length -1];
    var difference= lastItem-firstItem;
    var counter=0;

    for (var i=0;i<=difference;i++){
        arr.push(firstItem++);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(sorted.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    console.log(counter);
}

makeArrayConsecutive2([1,3,5]); //this works correctly and the output 
//is 2 since the numbers missing are 2 and 4 so 2 numbers

makeArrayConsecutive2([1,3,5,9,12]); //this outputs 5 when it should 
//output 7
```

Your first example worked because there were only three numbers, and even when treated as strings they would be sorted in the correct order. Your second array, on the other hand, when sorted as strings becomes `[1, 12, 3, 5, 9]` - you can log this yourself to see. By using the custom comparison function, the numbers are sorted correctly. For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Also a warning, because OP might not know it given the code: `sort` will sort an array *in-place*, then return it. Thus, `sorted` and `statues` are the same array, and if you expect `makeArrayConsecutive` to not mess `statues` up, you're in for a surprise.